# Increasing quota limits - conditions to meet

Tags: google-apps-script

We'd like to extend our quota limit from 1kk to around 20kk. We were already hitting limits, so we lowered frequency of our requests, and submitted https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/. We have filled the from thoroughly and sent it three times, always with negative response from google:

> Your quota extension application cannot be processed at this time
>   because of the following reasons:
>
> Bad data (invalid project number)

As it says in the form:

> The project number is a series of digits that can be found alongside
>   the Project ID in your Google Cloud Console.  Please comma separate
>   the project numbers without additional spaces

[image]

There is only one numeric `Project ID` we have. When I tried fill in the alphabetic one, we received :

> Project ID supplied does not exist.

When contacted Google Cloud Support, they told us that it is probably some bot who is answering this request, hence the generic answer. As well they directed us here: maybe someone of you had similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they wish you to use the item the arrow is pointing at in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Iam & Admin >> Settings

[image]